# Retain quality while mirroring jpg FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, images, jpeg

I can't seem to retain the color of a jpg file when I mirror via FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i "G:\My Drive\Adobe\Photoshop\Discord Emoji\yousellfish\Exports\yousellfish_2x.jpg" `
-vf hflip `
"G:\My Drive\Adobe\Photoshop\Discord Emoji\yousellfish\Exports\fishsellyou_2x.jpg"
```

As can be seen below the colors become noticeably washed out after the image is re-encoded via FFmpeg. I've tried setting the color range with `-color_range 2`, setting pixel format with `-pix_fmt rgb24`, flipping the image via metadata so I don't have to re-encode (never actually flipped it though), all of the above at once in a single command... nothing seems to work.

Before flipping:
[image]

After flipping:
[image]

Here's a video of me switching between the same jpg before and after I run it through FFmpeg using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "G:\My Drive\Adobe\Photoshop\Discord Emoji\yousellfish\Exports\yousellfish_2x.jpg" `
"G:\My Drive\Adobe\Photoshop\Discord Emoji\yousellfish\Exports\yousellfish_2xff.jpg"
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IjAAp33itc&feature=youtu.be

Another video showing the two photos compared in FFplay & Photoshop:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5waeo87-KM

Oddly with FFplay there doesn't seem to be a difference, but you can still see a difference in saturation when comparing the images in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a difference between the images here. Colorimetry parameters are identical (range, color space)

Additionally, signalstats filter detects no appreciable difference either.

Before:

```
lavfi.signalstats.YAVG=74.632
lavfi.signalstats.UAVG=110.517
lavfi.signalstats.VAVG=145.874
lavfi.signalstats.SATAVG=24.8496
lavfi.signalstats.HUEAVG=132.608
```

After:

```
lavfi.signalstats.YAVG=74.6508
lavfi.signalstats.UAVG=110.545
lavfi.signalstats.VAVG=145.902
lavfi.signalstats.SATAVG=24.8498
lavfi.signalstats.HUEAVG=132.721
```

Comment: I just edited the original post to include a video of me switching between the image before and after running it through FFmpeg, as can be seen in the video, the image encoded with FFmpeg is less saturated. I couldn't see any differences when probing it with FFprobe either, which makes it all the more confusing.

Comment: Check in other viewers, like ffplay or Photoshop..etc

Comment: I added another video to the original post showing comparisons with FFplay and Photoshop, there appears to be no difference when comparing them in FFplay, but there is definitely a difference in Photoshop. Not sure what this means, I'm always most inclined to "trust" FFplay... but the main problem is when I upload these images as emotes to a Discord server the difference in saturation shows. So it could just be that every other application is interpreting it incorrectly?

Comment: 4:4:4 is uncommon so I think other decoders are falling back on assumptions for 4:2:2 parsing behaviour, try with yuvj422p and color range 2

Comment: Adding `-pix_fmt yuvj422p -color_range 2` as options after the input didn't seem to change anything, do I need to put something on the input to let FFmpeg know what it's working with?